# How to import GeoJson file in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, geojson, mysql-innodb-cluster

I read many articles about mysql supporting spacial functions. But what i have not figured out is how to import Geojson file in mysql table so as to use spacial queries on it.

Is this possible in mysql?
If yes, can somebody mention the steps to do it?